# SQL: Aggregate Sum and Filtered Aggregate Sum

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I feel this is a super-basic question, but it is stumping me! Imagine I have a table (Revenue) that roughly looks like this:

```
Month     Product      Revenue
2019-01   Networking   1.00
2019-01   Computing    2.53
2019-01   Storage      4.88
2019-02   Networking   5.32
2019-02   Storage      6.20
...
```

All I want to do is summarise **total revenue by month** and **Networking Revenue by month** but for the life of me I can't wrap my head around how I'd do that (short of writing two queries). So the results should look something like:

```
Month     TotalRevenue  NetworkingRevenue
2019-01   8.41          1.00
2019-02   11.52         5.32
...
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`. Use a `case` expression to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```sql
SELECT 
  Month, 
  SUM(revenue) AS Revenue, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Product = 'Networking' THEN Revenue ELSE 0 END) AS Revenue_Networking
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Month
ORDER BY Month
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cd1176/1)

Answer (score 1):

use cases when

```
 select month,
 sum(case when Product='Networking' then Revenue else 0 end) as NetworkingRevenue,
 sum(Revenue) as TotalRevenue from table_name group by month
```